# How to split time data (in format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) to test and train sets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a time-series data with time to be in "`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`" format. I want to split my rows into train and test sets. But all the ways I tried to do this were failed.

How I can split the following data into test and train sets:

```
DATE-TIME          TEMP     PRE
2018-08-4 15:18:49 209.3851 4045.4414
2018-08-4 15:18:50 209.3851 4045.4314
2018-08-4 15:18:51 209.3581 4045.4268
2018-08-4 15:18:52 209.3553 4045.4343
2018-08-4 15:18:53 209.3553 4045.4307
...
```

Below code didn't work:

```
...
split_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-08-4 15:18:52')

train = data.loc[:split_date]
test = data.loc[split_date:]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your timestamps are sorted, so you can use

```
split_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-08-4 15:18:52')

train = df[df['DATE-TIME'] < split_date]
test = df[df['DATE-TIME'] > split_date]
```

results:

train:

```
DATE-TIME   TEMP    PRE
0   2018-08-04 15:18:49 209.3851    4045.4414
1   2018-08-04 15:18:50 209.3851    4045.4314
2   2018-08-04 15:18:51 209.3581    4045.4268
```

test:

```
DATE-TIME   TEMP    PRE
4   2018-08-04 15:18:53 209.3553    4045.4307
```

Maybe you have to convert your columntype to datetime format first:

```
df['DATE-TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE-TIME'])
```

If your timestamps are the index and not a column of the dataframe, just replace `df['DATE-TIME']` with `df.index`

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

split_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-08-4 15:18:52')

train = df[df.index < split_date]
test = df[df.index > split_date]
```

As an alternative you can have a look at [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) of `sklearn`.